# textbox.edit() returns unexpected characters

Tags: python-3.x, textbox, curses

I've developed a console application using curses.
The problem is curses.textpad.Textbox.edit() returns typed characters and some unexpected characters like 'qqqqqj'.

```py
import curses
from curses import textpad


def main(stdscr):
    curses.curs_set(0)
    window = stdscr.subwin(1, 10, 1, 1)
    window.clear()
    window.border()
    window2 = stdscr.subwin(2, 10, 3, 1)
    window2.clear()

    widget = textpad.Textbox(window, insert_mode=True)
    window.refresh()
    a = widget.edit()
    window2.addstr(0, 0, a)
    window2.refresh()

    curses.doupdate()
    window2.getch()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    curses.wrapper(main)
```

Terminal output is (for example):

> 123──────┘
>
> 123qqqqqqj

I can't understand what is it? And how to avoid it? Now I decided to use a.split('j')[0].

My environment:

1. python 3.6.0;
2. OS X.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you drew a border in the window that you used for editing text (and the odd characters are the border).  Make the editable window a *subwindow* of the window on which you draw a border.